# Compare 2 files (csv and text) using java

Tags: java, regex, multithreading, data-structures

I have 2 very big files (a csv and a text file, ard 1 million record in each). Both have similar data but not in the same order. I need to compare them using a java program. Could anyone suggest an efficient way to do this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: is it a one time operation ? If so, unix commands may be a better choice than java, to sort and compare the files. Anyway, you should provide more details, samples of the files + show us what you did to try to solve it, some code you wrote...

Comment: How big are the records?

Comment: Are records sorted?

Comment: No this is not a one time operation. That's the reason we need a program for this so that this would be done automatically. There will be around 50 fields in the record with approx 16k characters in a record. I am thinking of the approach as of now. I have not started coding of it since the project is just in the initial phase.

Comment: Hari Sadu, does my solution make sense to you?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding huge size, When you load such huge contents into Collection data structures like ArrayList, you may end up in OutOfMemoryError. To avoid this, you can increase the heap size for running your program.

As you want this to be done in Java, check if the below approach works for you.

```
Read file2 and load its records into a list.
foundCount=0
recordCount=0
Read file1. 
For each record in file1
{
 if(the record exists in the list) 
 {
  foundCount++
 }
 recordCount++
}
if(recordCount == foundCount && recordCount == list.size()) 
{
  file contents are same
}
else 
{
  file contents are different
}
```

Comment: Unless you sort file2 after you load it, that's going to take a very long time.